# Find a formula for $f(n)$ and prove it by induction

Tags: functions, induction

The following Problem:

«Find a formula for $f(n)$ and prove it by induction»

1. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(n) = f(n-1) -1$
2. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and $f(n) = 2*f(n-2)$

For the first one I thought of $f(n) = -n$

The induction basis holds:
$f(0) = -(0) = 0$.

For the step I get:
$f(n) = -n$

and $f(n) - (n+1) = f(n+1)$,

so I get $-2n-1 = f(n+1)$ instead of $-n-1$

Where is my fault in the induction?

For the Problem 2 I'm asking for some hints!
For every odd number the function is $0$, so I thought of something $((-1)^{n+1}+1)$ times something.

Thanks a lot Community!

Comment: You should have written $f(n) - 1 = f(n+1)$, for that is the rule given in (1).

Comment: For question 2, try writing out a few terms and see what you get.

Comment: Please formulate the title as a question, not as an order to the audience to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I get it. @tomglabst, I'll take that into consideration for my next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for problem 2:

By hand, you can check that the first terms of the sequence is going to look like:

$$0,1,0,2,0,4,0,8,0,16,\ldots$$

Killing the first and every other term with a factor of $(-1)^{n+1}+1$ works fine (but be aware that this factor becomes $2$ for odd $n$).

You need an expression which goes through the different powers of $2$, but only for odd $n$'s, so $2^n$ won't work. Can you see what will work?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the hint.
I got the following idea:

$((-1)^{n+1}+1)2^{((n+1)/2)-2}$

I think this guy works out just fine!

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: Since I'm a newbie here, what would be an appropriate title for that kind of problem? (since tomglabst didnt like the title)

Comment: I would go for a title like "What is $f$, when $f(n) = f(n-2)$ and $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$?" or "Solving linear recurrence relations by induction". As long as you can somewhat tell the content of the problem from the title, you should be fine.